# Analytics for Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-cloud-storage

Where to start? I am searching for a way to track who is pulling media from our public links on the Google Cloud Storage platform. We use it to serve up audio and video podcast for our website. I've scoured Google's documentation and couldn't find a solution. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage offers access logs.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs?hl=en

It's not enabled by default, but you can set it up so it delivers the access logs to cloud storage bucket and then you can read with any tool. They even give you tips on how to load the logs into Google BigQuery so you can use that tool to query the logs more easily.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a bunch! I'll dig into those whenever I collect some nice data.